# On refresh react route giving 404 error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have routes

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route exact path="/ViewUser" component={ViewUser} />
    <Route exact path="/AddUser" component={AddUser}/>
</Router>
```

When i click on link like viewuser it renders viewuser component

But when i refresh page on viewuser its give me 404 error.

Comment: [This is possibly duplicate for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) This post may help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually